# Which UX principle would address user diversion after login?

Tags: usability, design-principles

I was wondering what potential UX principles or heuristics might be  broken in the following situation so that I could conduct more research on the topic.

The situation: A task is being conducted by a user, and after a few clicks into the task, the system requires the user to login. After successful login, the user is then taken to a different page, no longer in the task they were performing, with no clear navigation back to the task.

What principles, if any, does this violate?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of heuristics that might be violated in this scenario:

- **User Control and Freedom** - You're interfering with the task that the user was performing, causing a temporary loss of control (until they get back on the happy path);
- **Recognition Over Recall** - You're forcing the user to remember how to get back to the next step in the task they were trying to complete without any cues (unless you have a section called "Recently Visited Pages" or the like.)

Answer (score 0):

Not so much of a principle, but it would fail a **Task Analysis** since it removed the user from achieving their goal.

Taskflow Analysis - [https://methods.18f.gov/decide/task-flow-analysis/#:~:text=A%20step%2Dby%2Dstep%20analysis,in%20pursuit%20of%20their%20goal](https://methods.18f.gov/decide/task-flow-analysis/#:%7E:text=A%20step%2Dby%2Dstep%20analysis,in%20pursuit%20of%20their%20goal).

Additionally, a somewhat related principle is that of **Reciprocity**, dicussed here - https://www.nngroup.com/articles/login-walls/

> once you’ve helped users smoothly complete their transaction, they may be grateful for a pleasant experience and willing to create an account.

and **Interaction Cost**, discusssed here - https://www.nngroup.com/articles/interaction-cost-definition/

> the sum of efforts — mental and physical — that the users must deploy in interacting with a site in order to reach their goals.

Answer (score 0):

A quote that is seen a lot is:

> “If we want users to like our software, we should design it to behave like a likeable person: respectful, generous and helpful.”

<sub>— Alan Cooper, Software Designer and Programmer</sub>

The flow described is not helpful and even a bit disrespectful to the user.